# How to call function on anchor tag click

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have one panel as xtype:'label'

I want to call a function when I click on the text in anchor tag.

can we do this in sencha touch.

Comment: Use event delegation in Sencha Touch, post the code for detailed answer

Comment: Hi Viswa ,Actually when I click on anchor tag I want to call function which is defined in controller.Is this possible. I I use xtype:"button" I know I can get using event.id but can it be possible using xtype:'label'

Comment: How? Can you provide some code... or some Idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    html: '<a href="#" onclick="MyApp.app.getController(\'ControllerName\').myFunction(); return false;">My link</a>'
}
```